# Power BI - Timeseries compare two different start dates

Tags: date, powerbi, time-series, powerbi-desktop, timeserieschart

I want to compare how different campaigns are progressing based on number of days into the campaign rather than by date (see day1, day2, etc... on the x-axis below).

Here is my DAX code, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated...

```
**Normalised Campaign Metrics =
VAR DateReached = CALCULATE(MIN(Days[Day]),db[PAYMENT_DATE]<> BLANK(), KEEPFILTERS(db[PRODUCT_CODE SWITCH]))
VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(db[PAYMENT_DATE]),KEEPFILTERS(db[PRODUCT_CODE SWITCH]))
VAR DayNo = SELECTEDVALUE(Days[Day])
RETURN CALCULATE(count(db[PAYMENT_DATE]),
FILTER(ALL(db[PAYMENT_DATE]),
DateReached+DayNo && DateReached+DayNo<=MaxDate))**
```

Many thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GchBK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend solving this through manipulating your actual data rather than a complex DAX measure. If you are familiar with star schema modelling, I would solve this problem by adding a new column to your fact table that calculates how many days from the start date the payment occurred and then connect this column to a new "Days Passed" dimension that is simply a list of numbers from 1 to however many days you need. Then, you can use this new dimension as the source data for your x axis and use a standard payment amount measure for your y axis.

Comment: Thanks Antyan, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a dimension table as the relative basis to comparison with inactive relationship. Here is a video about it:

https://youtu.be/knXFVf2ipro

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.